# no main manifest attribute, in app.war

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a WAR file which I want to deploy in Docker but when I run it with associated Port after build, I am getting this error:
`no main manifest attribute, in app.war`.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM java:8                                                                                                                                                             
EXPOSE 8080                                                                                                                                                             
ADD /service.war app.war                                                                                                                                                
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.war"]`
```

What should be done to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a tomcat, not a java image. You can try even without Dockerfile. Launch this command on the same dir as your .war file:

```
docker run --name myTomcat -p 8080:8080 --rm -i -v $(pwd)/service.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war tomcat
```

This will launch a Tomcat server with your war deployed and the port 8080 mapped from your container to your docker host machine. I hope it helps.

Comment: You can access directly on your localhost because with taht command we mapped the port from your docker container to your docker host. Try `http://localhost:8080/something` and replace "something" with the appropiate (it depends of the content of your .war file).

Comment: I tried that too but the link is running only the Tomcat server not the war file.

Comment: This is not a docker problem. You must know what .war has inside and you should put the needed path. Be pretty sure that the .war file has what you expect.

Comment: Sure, will see to it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. My problem was the following configuration in fabric8 docker-maven-plugin:

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>docker-build</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

Building docker image was bound to maven *package* phase, which means building the jar file itself was not finished when I was triggering docker image build. Once I updated execution phase to anything later than *package*, e.g. verify or install, the issue was gone.